# HTTPS module in nodeJS get method

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, backend

I am planning to parse JSON after making a get request with the node HTTPS module. I saw the documentation but was unable to understand the part highlighted below. I want to know more about *res.on('data', (d) => { process.stdout.write(d); })* method. How it fetches the data?
const https = require('https');

'''

```
https.get('someUrl', (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  *res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });*

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

'''

Comment: you are using the  HTTP request API and the bit you do not understand is in truth very simple to grasp: you are attaching the `data` event to the response object so that for the argument you pass into the arrow function, it prints the result (d) through process.stdout.write (or in other words console.log). How it fetches the data? https.get() makes a server side call to the url provided and it then returns a response object you can access to. **Clear**?

Comment: Yea, it's clear now. I am new to this, so trying to wrap my head around the concepts.

Thank you for explaining.

Comment: no problem, please note that in your code, (d) is a buffer, not a string as you may expect

Comment: Yes, I saw that when I was trying to console.log(d), then I used JSON.parse(d) to get the proper output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add some information about rags2riches comment, the function associated to res.on('url', function) will be called for every chunk of data received and d will basically contain the data of this chunk.
If you want to do something when you have received everything, you should use res.on('close', function) or res.on('end', function).
An example here: https://blog.bearer.sh/node-http-request/

Comment: Thank you for the link. It was helpful.